# Expand a html box from the centre using css and keyframe animations

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a box (or circle) to expand and contract from the centre rather than top left, but it just will not happen for me. Could anyone please advise.

Here is my code so far.

html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="css/expanding_box.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="BoxBreath"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.BoxBreath {
    top:300px;
    left:300px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#C0F;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-name: breath;
}
@keyframes breath {
    from {
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scale instead of changing the width and height. This way, you can remove the transform-origin, and it should go from the centre. Also, depending on what you want, it may be better to separate the keyframes as percentages, and double the duration:

```
@keyframes breath{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
}
```

The advantage of using additional keyframes is that you could change 50% to, say, 65%, for a better breath effect, or add another keyframe so it pauses between "breaths".

Here is everything altogether, including support for different browsers:

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CFhN/1/)**</kbd>

```
.BoxBreath{
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #C0F;
  animation: breath linear 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: breath linear 2s infinite;
  -moz-animation: breath linear 2s infinite;
  -o-animation: breath linear 2s infinite;
  -ms-animation: breath linear 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes breath{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes breath{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes breath {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes breath {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes breath {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(0) scaleY(0) ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Rc9fa/54/)**</kbd>

```
.BoxBreath {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    background: #000;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
}
```